# To create zip file that containing mdf file in C#

Tags: c#, sql, dotnetzip

I have .mdf and .ldf file in my local device. I want to create zip that two files. I use DonetZip. But it didn't show me any error and also the program is not working. How should I do and I want some example to zip .mdf and .ldf files.

Comment: Are you trying to zip a live MDF & LDF file? (Meaning a running SQLServer database files). If this is the case the files are locked.

Comment: Ensure the file isn't locked and you have read permission. Ensure you have write permission for where you are creating the file. Ensure all paths are absolute and correct.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddFile(@"C:\SomeFile.mdf");
    zip.AddFile(@"C:\SomeFile.ldf");
    zip.Save(@"C:\zippedfolder.zip");
}
```

Comment: Yes. I write the same code. The database is already detach with server. When I run the program. The program doesn't work anything. No errors are shown. :(

Comment: Have you tried to rename or move the file to make sure it isn't locked